# apply condition before calling a library extension method in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to apply a condition before the library extension method call I have the following code. I am using a nuget Package.

```
var trans = new transbuilder(key)
.Toaddress(line, city, country)
.FromAddress(line, city, country)
.Create(); // uses transModel
```

now I want to call `FromAddress` only if I have a some flag equals to true e.g.

```
var trans = new transbuilder(key)  // trans is some library which contains different methods
.Toaddress(line, city, country)
(flag) ? .FromAddress(line, city, country) : "" ,
.Create(); // uses transModel;
```

but the above is not possible. Is there any way to achieve this ?

possible solution is

```
if(flag)
{
var trans = new transbuilder(key)
.Toaddress(line, city, country)
.FromAddress(line, city, country)
.Create(); // uses transModel
}
else
{
var trans = new transbuilder(key)
.Toaddress(line, city, country)
.Create(); // uses transModel
}
```

but I don't want this solution because it will make my code lengthy since I have to call multiple extension methods.

The below is inside the meta data

```
public class TransBuilder 
{
public TransBuilder(string key);
public TransModel Create();
public TransBuilder ToAddress(string line ,string city , string country);
public TransBuilder FromAddress(string line ,string city , string country);

}
```

Comment: Fluent syntax is not something that should be shoehorned into each scenario. You cannot trivially _and_ readably make conditional method calls in such a chain. Just use `;\r\n if (flag) trans.FromAddress(...);`. Or get creative and write your own `.When(flag)` extension method and go wild.

Comment: actually, i am using a NuGet package's extension methods. can't just add my own into that.

Comment: @Haroonnasir That's not true, you can write extension methods for any class, the extension doesn't have to be within the same package or assembly as the original class. The Microsoft documentation for this topic (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) actually shows an extension method on `String`...and clearly that is not in the same assembly as the code which extends it! Please research the topic more thoroughly before making assumptions. P.S. Please see my answer below and check if it's working or is what you are looking for.

Comment: What kind of datatype `Toaddress` method returns. If It is string then there will be no such method after `string.FromAddress` what expect 3 parameters? From your code 2 I thought `var trans` is a string type. But it is not when I see 3rd code.

Comment: The key thing for us to know here, in order to be sure about the correct answer, is to know the return type of `.Toaddress` (and also the return type of `FromAddress` would be helpful information too). Can you please provide that information rather than tinkering with minor details in your question?

Comment: @ADyson actually TransBuilder itself is a class and all the extension methods have the `TransBuilder ` return type including the `.Toaddress`  .

Comment: `Trans itself is a class` ...so there is another type called `Trans`? or are you talking about `transbuilder`? Where does `transModel` come into it? Please, just give us the full, straightforward picture instead of little bits of ambiguous/incomplete info. Just list the method signatures of all the methods, that's all you need to do. Also, I assume that the code in your first example actually works, yes? no errors in that one?

Comment: No its actually `TransBuilder` made a typo there ... like I said its a nugget package I am using which does not provide much info as far as inside code is concerned .

Comment: `which does not provide much info as far as inside code is concerned` ...visual studio can tell you the method signatures of all the public methods. So please just list here the signatures of all the methods you are using in your question. It's simple to do that.  We're not concerned about the inside of the methods, only the outside.

Comment: Typo in your update... ToAddress is listed twice. FromAddress is not there.

Comment: i have updated my question to get you a clear picture . now if use `IF` in between I get that error of conversion but when used without it it runs fine .

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely that a boring, regular old `if` statement is all you need. However you do need separate variables - one for the builder and one for the model which is created at the end.

So, how about this:

```
var transB = new transbuilder(key).ToAddress(line, city, country);
if (flag) transB = transB.FromAddress(line, city, country); 
var transM = transB.Create();
```

This is much less verbose than your 3rd example. There is no reason to write the `var trans =...` line twice.

Comment: i actually used this but i have a  method that is create which has the transModel Data type . when I use it without `if` it runs e.g. in normal scenario but when I tried yours to it gives an error of  `Cannot implicitly convert transbuilder to transModel` .

Comment: Like I said in the description, this answer is partially guesswork because we don't know the return types of the ToAddress or FromAddress methods. If you provide this simple information then we can give you a 100% answer.

Comment: These have the tranBuilder return types and transbuilder() is a constructor of TransBuilder .

Comment: @Haroonnasir updated the answer. Should make sense now...you just need two different variables..one for the builder, and another for the model which comes out at the end.

Comment: Now that can work .. Hope it does the logic stuff too.thanks ..

Comment: why wouldn't it "do the logic stuff" (whatever exactly you really mean by that) do you think? What's your concern, specifically? Test it, and you'll find out anyway. It performs exactly the same function as your 3rd example, but with less code.

Comment: yeah i will .. i am confident it will solve the problem .

Answer (score 1):

One should fight "fluent syntax" or "method chaining" with all available power. It only works if the interface is well-designed and the chaining obvious and extensible, such as with Linq's extension methods (`foo.Zip(...).Where(...).OrderBy(...).Select(...).ToList()`). This code you show is not.

Mere object initialization code should not use fluent syntax. If all the builder does is `return this;` so you can call the next method on whatever it returns, then the whole thing only exists to please the developer of the library.

What is wrong with the following?

```
var transaction = new Transaction(key)
{
    ToAddress = new Address(line, city, country),
    FromAddress = cond ? new Address(line, city, country) : null;
};
```

It is unsurprisingly boring, yes, and ew, lots of curly braces, but it is idiomatic C# as we have been writing for more than 13 years already, since the introduction of C# 3.0. I'm not a grumpy old man, I just loathe fluent syntax where it is unnecessary.

To answer your question: use an `if()`, which has also been in the language since its invocation:

```
var trans = new transbuilder(key)
    .ToAddress(line, city, country);
if (flag) 
{
    trans.FromAddress(line, city, country);
}
```

Because you're probably not interested in the return value of `FromAddress()` anyway, as it's most likely a method that modifies the internal state of the builder and returns `this` just for fluent syntax's sake.

If you want to get creative, you could create your own extension method:

```
public static TransactionBuilder CallIf(this TransactionBuilder builder, bool condition, Func<TransactionBuilder, TransactionBuilder> action)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        builder = action(builder);
    }
    
    return builder;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var trans = new TransactionBuilder(key)
    .AddToAddress(...)
    .CallIf(cond, b => b.AddFromAddress(...));
```

But don't.

Comment: Yeah this is opinionated, but I hate abusing syntax with a burning passion.

Comment: this can help too. will consider this . Thanks .